# How can I build a power bank which charges to 16.8 V and outputs 12 V?

Tags: lithium-ion, batteries

I am working on a battery pack building project to drive a small 12 V electric motor (7 A max. current draw), and I have gotten this far:

- I will use Li-ion 18650 cells in a 6P4S configuration;
- I will wire up the cells in parallel first, series second;
- I will use a balancing 4S BMS with balance wires connected between each of the units in the series.

The motor is rated for 11-15 V, so at max. voltage, the battery would be out of range. Because of this, I want to use a buck converter to output a steady 12 V.

Where I am a bit lost then is: how can I charge the battery?  Do I just wire an input path and output path in parallel, with a buck converter set to 16.8 V on the input and 12 V on the output, or do I need some other components there?

Comment: The idea of using a buck to get down to 12 V is probably good, as the Li-ion batteries should always be well enough higher that it will work okay. The part about charging the battery is entirely different with a 4S6P. Technically, you should want to charge each one independently as only then can you follow the correct charging procedure. Of course, chargers that are sold over the counter will do anything you want. And no, you do NOT want to charge a 4S6P to 12 V!

Comment: That's why laptops have 19V power supplies: to charge their 16.8V batteries that supply 12V to the computer.

Comment: I'd look at drone parts. There is an entire subculture that does nothing all day except solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Where I am a bit lost then is: how can I charge the battery?

A power bank has two power ports: an input an an output.

```
Power input --> charger --> BMS --> DC-DC-converter --> DC output
                             |
                           Cells
```

For example, if your power source is 120 Vac:

```
    120 Vac --> charger --> BMS --> DC-DC-converter --> DC output
                             |
                           Cells
```

For another example, if your power source is 24 V DC:

```
24 Vdc input  --> CCCV DC-DC converter--> BMS --> DC-DC-converter --> DC output
                                           |
                                         Cells
```

Absolute best solution: don't reinvent the wheel. Buy a [ready-made 12 V power bank](https://www.google.com/search?q=12+V+power+bank). They are plentiful, reliable, well built, have a warranty, meet safety regulation, nicely enclosed, and cheaper that you can buy the parts, let alone build one.

Answer (score 0):

> "Where I am a bit lost is: how can I charge the battery? Do I just wire an input path and output path in parallel?"

First off, I'm new to this part as well. But this is the idea yes.

Your Li-ion charger will do its constant current (CC) and constant voltage (CV) charging. But it is not just charging the battery, it is also powering a "parasitic load". So especially during the CC phase it will charge the battery a bit slower depending on how much current the motor is pulling. Turning it off during charging is ideal.

The charger should be a lithium charger configured for your 4S pack. And the charger is wired to the main battery positive and negative terminals. Use a BMS with both balancing and over- and undervoltage protection.

The other parts of your circuit don't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

The charging is done through the bms as this is the point of using it, because lithium batteries need to be charged with the current not exceeding certain threshold for example 1 Amp, and at the same time the batter's voltage shouldn't reach higher than 4.2v.

I always found cc/cv hard to understand, but it's actually very easy, the battery will get damaged if it draws current higher than max ratings for example 1 Amp, it will also get damaged if it was charged over 4.2v, the empty battery should start at 3v it has a resistance if you applied 4.2v it might draw a lot of current, the charger reduces the voltage until the current draw is safe to for example 3.5v, but it should keep increasing the voltage as the battery charges up to 4.2v then stop charging.
note : if you applied 100v to the battery it will explode (I had to say it) because the current it draws will be very high, but if you added a circuit which maintains constant current the voltage will drop to the appropriate voltage for example 3.5v and the remaining voltage will be circulated through the circuit so it also might damage the circuit.

The bms's job is to make sure that no battery gets overcharged, undercharged, and some extra features, batteries are made different so if you bought 2 3000 mah batteries you might find 1 at 2900 mah and the other at 2950 mah so one will charge faster and the other will still need to be charged so a bms will cut current from the charged one and keep it on the one that still needs to be charged.